# I can't run C++ code

Tags: c++

I Can't Run Program
Error message :

[image]

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;  
int main() 
{  
  cout << "C++";  
  return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First install the compilers if you already have not.

```
sudo apt install build-essential
```

Compile the program with `g++ /path/to/filename.cpp -o /path/to/output`  (note that `gcc` may not work with programs written in C++. You would need `g++`).

Then run the program with `/path/to/output`.

---

Your code worked for me. I saved your code in the file `new.cpp`, and compiled it to an executable named `output`.

```
[archisman@home-pc ~]$ g++ new.cpp -o output
[archisman@home-pc ~]$ ./output 
C++
```

Answer (score 0):

after doing

```
 sudo apt install build-essential
```

if it shows the same error, just save the file and then compile and run the program.
That resolved it for me.

Comment: This is just a less complete version of the other answer isn’t it?

Comment: @Will yes it is a subset of the above Ans. I just wanted to include the saving part. :)